# Excel Pivot Date Filter on Previous Business Day

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have scoured stackoverflow for an answer to this but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604784/filter-excel-pivot-table-based-on-previous-business-day) is all I found.

I want to filter data in a pivot table in excel based on the previous business day. I know I need to modify the vba but am not sure how to write it.

Could anyone help a brother out?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably add another column in your original data - which would have the previous business day. Then include this column in your pivot table. This is probably the easiest solution I can think of.

You can use the formula to get previous business day.

```
IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=1,A2-2,IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=2,A2-3,A2-1))
```

(assuming Cell A2 as your date)

This would give you Friday as previous business day for Saturday, Sunday and Monday. For the rest of the days - its just the previous day

Hope this helps. In case you don't want to use this approach, let me know, I can try to think of some other solution.

Comment: I really appreciate your input! However I am reporting on a few different dates and wanted to avoid having to use formulas in the raw data if possible. Is there a way to apply that formula in the VBA?